# Python: compare strings of a column between two excel sheets and find the matching columns and write to another data frame

Tags: python, pandas, string, text, comparison

I need to read two spreadsheets(lets say SS1 and SS2). Then have to read the description column in SS1 and search for similar description on latest date in SS2. Have to write the output in another spreadsheet with the unique matching descriptions with its latest date and price.

Input and Output samples below for reference:
SS1:

| S.No | Product | Product_Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Shirt | Monte Carlo Men Shirt |
| 2 | Shirt | Belmonte Shirt Cotton |
| 3 | Shirt | US Polo tshirt men |
| 4 | Shirt | Monte Carlo tshirt |
| 5 | Shirt | Monte Carlo Men Shirt |
| 6 | Suit | Louis Philippe wrinkle free |
| 7 | Suit | Park Avenue |
| 8 | Suit | Van Heusen |
| 9 | Watches | Titan Men Wrist Type |
| 10 | Watches | Casio |
| 11 | Watches | Titan Women Wrist Type |
| 12 | Watches | Rolex |
| 13 | Watches | Casio |

SS2:

| S.No | Product | Product_Description | Purchase_Date | Quantity | Price | Net Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Watches | Casio | Jan-19 | 10 | 5000 | 50000 |
| 2 | Watches | Rolex | May-20 | 2 | 500000 | 1000000 |
| 3 | Shirt | Monte Carlo tshirt | Feb-20 | 20 | 2000 | 40000 |
| 4 | Suit | Raymond | Jan-20 | 50 | 10000 | 500000 |
| 5 | Watches | Lois Moinet | May-21 | 3 | 60000 | 180000 |
| 6 | Shirt | Peter England | Apr-21 | 40 | 1800 | 72000 |
| 7 | Watches | Casio | Mar-19 | 30 | 5500 | 165000 |
| 8 | Shirt | Monte Carlo Men Shirt | Jun-19 | 10 | 3000 | 30000 |
| 9 | Shirt | Monte Carlo Men Shirt | Apr-20 | 12 | 3100 | 37200 |
| 10 | Watches | Rolex | Dec-20 | 4 | 505000 | 2020000 |
| 11 | Suit | Louis Philippe wrinkle free suit | Jun-21 | 9 | 20000 | 180000 |
| 12 | Suit | Allen Solly | Jan-21 | 12 | 4000 | 48000 |
| 13 | Shirt | Monte Carlo tshirt | Apr-21 | 15 | 2500 | 37500 |

Output:

| S.No | Product | Product_Description | Purchase_Date | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Shirt | Monte Carlo Men Shirt | Apr-20 | 3100 |
| 2 | Shirt | Monte Carlo tshirt | Apr-21 | 2500 |
| 3 | Suit | Louis Philippe wrinkle free suit | Jun-12 | 20000 |
| 4 | Watches | Casio | Mar-19 | 5500 |
| 5 | Watches | Rolex | Dec-20 | 505000 |

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
temp = SS1.merge(SS2, on=['Product', 'Product_Description'])[['S.No_x', 'Product', 'Product_Description', 'Purchase_Date', 'Price']]
    
res = temp.sort_values(['Product_Description','Purchase_Date']).drop_duplicates('Product_Description', keep='last')    
res=res.rename(columns={'S.No_x':'S.No'})
res=res.sort_values('S.No')
res.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
        
print(res)
```

Output:

```
   S.No  Product    Product_Description Purchase_Date   Price
0     4    Shirt     Monte Carlo tshirt        Feb-20    2000
1     5    Shirt  Monte Carlo Men Shirt        Jun-19    3000
2    12  Watches                  Rolex        May-20  500000
3    13  Watches                  Casio        Mar-19    5500
```

If you want the ACTUAL LATEST DATE (not latest in dataset), insert the following line as 2nd in the above code:

```
temp['Purchase_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(temp['Purchase_Date'], format='%b-%d')
```

Comment: Thanks, it works well, but not fully. I got 
/**
raise KeyError(f"{not_found} not in index")
**/
As I have used few more columns from ss2 referred. Seems its asking me to use loc, iloc. Am I right?

Comment: @JoaTzimas, on the same merge function, how to use location based parameters to avoid "   raise KeyError(f"{not_found} not in index")   " ?